# HTTPS status code 0 while accessing IBM Watson API through Hololens

Tags: https, firewall, ibm-watson, hololens

```
credentials = new Credentials(tokenOptions, _serviceUrl);

     if(credentials != null) Debug.Log("Credentials is not null!");
     //  Wait for tokendata
     while (!credentials.HasIamTokenData())
     {
         Debug.Log("In the while loop"); // INFINITE LOOP ON Hololens
         yield return null;
     }
```

I get an infinte loop in the above code. This is in `Watson.cs`

It works well in Unity editor. This issue occurs when deployed into Hololens. I checked the `RESTConnector.cs` file from `Watson SDK`, I am getting a `HTTPS status code 0`, but I get `status code 200` for Unity editor. I am not sure why this is happening. If its a `firewall` issue, how do I fix it in Hololens?

Answer (score 0):

To enable the network capability of the device, you need to enable [InternetClient]  under Publishing Settings/Capabilities. This tutorial shows the specific explanation of these capabilities: [Capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-capability). And check Unity guidance for capability setting:[Universal Windows Player settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html).

In addition, according to the experience of previous cases([WSA] ISNETWORKERROR ALWAYS RETURN TRUE WHEN RUNNING AN UWP APP ON X86 ARCHITECTURE(https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/wsa-isnetworkerror-always-return-true-when-running-an-uwp-app-on-86x-architecture)) ,a few specific versions of unity will make the project get some network issues after the project is built. Therefore, if the issue still occurs after enable [InternetClient], please provide the version of unity that you are using.